# How can i add a UIImagePickerController controller to my ipad based application to show multiple images?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

i  am using uiimage picker control in ipad based application.so i am displaying it  using the following code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:myImagePicker animated:YES];
```

but there is a error that shows

```
'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'
```

how can i add a UIImagePickerController controller  to my ipad based application to show multiple images.can any one provide me a good way to do it.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9019460/78336

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.When you click on a button in button action call this.

```
UIActionSheet *photoActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose Existing",nil];

        [photoActionSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(315, 355, 10, 10) inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController modalTransitionStyle]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x644a990'

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:popoverController animated:YES];
this code making problem

Comment: please look at the above answer

Comment: how can i display multipple images in this.

Comment: after that call the delegate methods.see the second answer

Comment: i dont want the buttons .just need to show multiple images and  need get the image details whenever i click one of the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark UIActionSheetDelegate methods

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    imgPicker.delegate = self;


    if(buttonIndex == 0){

            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
                imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];

        }


    else if(buttonIndex == 1){


            imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];


    }

}
```

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

Comment: let you know my questions is "i am using uiimage picker control in ipad based application"