# Using presentModalViewController with UIImagePickerController causing Crash on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, uiimagepickercontroller

Using presentModalViewController with UIImagePickerController causing Crash on iOS 5 (its running fine on version<5), i am trying to get all the albums on the device, using 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum' is only getting the Camera images, so when i change the sourceType to 'UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary' it crashes, i appreciate any help, here is my code:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if(version < 5) 
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    else                        
        imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        //imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: when using iOS 5 it crashes on this line: [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];

Comment: Whats the crash message / exception information?

Comment: I have the very same problem (iOS5, iPad, Landscape). Presenting the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera works just fine, but UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary and UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum don't. Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I found another post saying the `UIImagePickerController` you present should be stored as a variable in the presenting class to prevent it from being deallocated too early. This unfortunately didn't help me...

Comment: That solved my problem on iPad. It indeed needs to be created as a popover: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015155/how-to-use-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ipad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official doc:

> To use an image picker controller containing its default controls, perform these steps:
>
> 1. Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired source. Do this calling the isSourceTypeAvailable: class method, providing a constant from the “UIImagePickerControllerSourceType” enum.
> 2. Check which media types are available, for the source type you’re using, by calling the availableMediaTypesForSourceType: class method. This lets you distinguish between a camera that can be used for video recording and one that can be used only for still images.
> 3. Tell the image picker controller to adjust the UI according to the media types you want to make available—still images, movies, or both—by setting the mediaTypes property.
> 4. Present the user interface by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.
>
>    On iPad, present the user interface using a popover. Doing so is valid only if the sourceType property of the image picker controller is set to UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. To use a popover controller, use the methods described in “Presenting and Dismissing the Popover” in UIPopoverController Class Reference.
> 5. When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image or movie, or cancels the operation, dismiss the image picker using your delegate object. For newly-captured media, your delegate can then save it to the Camera Roll on the device. For previously-saved media, your delegate can then use the image data according to the purpose of your app

Maybe point 4 is causing troubles.

Comment: it is saying "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" , it works fine if when i change the source type to following, thanks for your response; imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

Comment: i even tried this line of code but still not working, cant figure out why :(  ::    [self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:^{NSLog(@"Photo Albums Presented");}];

Comment: Are you testing this on an iPad or iPhone? Because on iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController

Comment: thanks, but i am using iPhone with iOS 5 and the code is not working, any idea how i can make it work? i appreciate your continuos replies.

Comment: its resolved now, Thanks alot for the help, i was missing one of the steps you mentioned above.