# How to add the UIImagePickerController in the custom view?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How to add the UIImagePickerController in the view ? If I add the image picker to the view, its show on the full screen. I need to show the on the centre of the view, But UIImagePickerController hide the navigation bar.

How add the UIImagePickerController in the view and also show the navigation bar ?

I am using the following code, I got the output like this(screenshot).

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
imagePicker.showsCameraControls     = NO;
imagePicker.navigationBarHidden     = NO;
imagePicker.toolbarHidden           = YES;
imagePicker.wantsFullScreenLayout   = NO;
imagePicker.delegate                = self;
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView       = cameraOverlayView;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I need some for show the navigation bar while add the UIImagePickerController in the view. Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are develop application for iPad then you can use popoverviewcontroller to show imagepickerviewcontroller with navigation bar

please see thie link :

[How to use UIImagePickerController in iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015155/how-to-use-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ipad)

Comment: No, My application only for the iPhone. so I need to add UIImagePickerController in the view. as well as show the navigation bar on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Correct way to customize media capture [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007070-CH3-SW54) using Assets Library.

Simple way (in some cases) is using overlay view with frame size of whole screen and add   controls on that view which simulate navigation bar.

```
    if (_pickerOverlay == nil) {
    _pickerOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    //red transparent tint for demo
    _pickerOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0
                                                     green:0.0
                                                      blue:0.0 alpha:0.6];

    UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 250, 40);
    [btnBack setTitle:@"Custom buttom" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [_pickerOverlay addSubview:btnBack];
}

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.cameraOverlayView = _pickerOverlay;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you. I need, how can I set the frame for the cameraOverlayView ? Because the camera view start from top edge(no navigation, status bar). I don't want like this, I need how to show navigation bar with  cameraOverlayView ? Please give your suggestions.

Comment: @Mani In your case you should create custom view controller and get media capture features with AV Foundation Library. Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)